# Datepicker update ui time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have datepicker with year and month select

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DXBh.png

after changing the date it reflects in input , but opening again shows date now instead of selected one

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E5lB.png

```
$('[month_day_picker]').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm",
      //  yearRange: '2016:+0',
        beforeShow : function() {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('custom-hide-calendar');
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").removeClass('custom-hide-calendar');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting.

Comment: could you show some code of what you have done ??

Comment: That's not possible. You didn't even post your code. But see here https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year. Maybe this link would help you.